# Sharing Image and Text On twitter not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-spinner, android-twitter

This is my code given below.FrameLayout is Used to share as JPEG Image on twitter.This is the code Im trying .

```
sharesp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnrShare);
        sharesp.setAdapter(new MyShAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.rowview, Sharestring));
        sharesp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                selectitem=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                selecetint=position;

                if(selectitem=="FaceBook" || selecetint==R.drawable.fbbtn){
                       shareFbook();

                }
                else if(selectitem=="Twitter" || selecetint==R.drawable.twitbtn){
                    shareTwitter();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


public void shareTwitter(){

         FrameLayout savFrame_layout=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame);
        try {
            if(MainActivity.this.mainFrame_layout==null){
            MainActivity.this.mainFrame_layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
              MainActivity.this.mainFrame_layout.refreshDrawableState();
              MainActivity.this.mainFrame_layout.buildDrawingCache();

            MainActivity.this.bm_ImgFrame = mainFrame_layout.getDrawingCache();

        int i1=100000;
        Random random=new Random();
        i1=random.nextInt(i1);
           MainActivity.fname = "Quick_"+ i1 + ".jpg";

            String pathy=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"/MYAnApps";
            MainActivity.this.rootFile=new File(pathy);

            MainActivity.this.sdImageMainDirectory = new File(MainActivity.this.rootFile + MainActivity.fname);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(MainActivity.this.sdImageMainDirectory);
            bm_ImgFrame.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fileOutputStream);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(MainActivity.this.sdImageMainDirectory.getAbsolutePath());

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("/*");
                intent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android.PostActivity");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "MyAndroidApp: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.MyApp");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(MainActivity.this.sdImageMainDirectory));
                startActivity(intent);            
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"*/*"` as MIME, so you can send any generic data type.

```
 intent.setType("*/*");
```

Also try changing `ACTION_SEND` to `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` which specialized for delivering multiple data.

More info about [ACTION_SEND_MULTPLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and handling MIME types.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Example this is working for me

[Twitter Image And text sharing Example](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/sharing-text-image-in-twitter-android-example/)

twitter sharing using this one

```
  private void showTwittDialog() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.twitt_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Twitter");

    Button btnPost = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnpost);
    final EditText et = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.twittext);
    et.setText(sharingStr);
    et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
    btnPost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              twitt_msg = et.getText().toString().trim();   
            if (twitt_msg.length() == 0) {
                showToast("Tweet is empty!!!");
                return;
            } else if (twitt_msg.length() > 140) {
                showToast("Tweet of more than 140 characters not allowed!!!");
                return;
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            new PostTwittTask().execute(twitt_msg);
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}

protected void Share_to_twitter() {  
    Intent tweetIntent = new Intent();
    tweetIntent.setType("text/plain");
    tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharingStr);
    final PackageManager packageManager =  getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(tweetIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list) {
        twitter_dialog = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
    }

    if (twitter_dialog != null  && twitter_dialog.startsWith("com.twitter.android")) {
        // if the native twitter app is found
        tweetIntent.setPackage(twitter_dialog);
        startActivity(tweetIntent);
    } else {
        showTwittDialog();
    }
    mTwitter.resetAccessToken();        
}

class PostTwittTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        pDialog.setMessage("Posting Twitt...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... twitt) {
        try {
            mTwitter.updateStatus(twitt[0]);
            return "success";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getMessage().toString().contains("duplicate")) {
                return "Posting Failed because of Duplicate message...";
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Posting Failed!!!";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (null != result && result.equals("success")) {               
            View popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.share_successfully_popup,null);   
            final PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow(popUpView,UtilityClass.dynamicScalingForWidth(100),
                    UtilityClass.dynamicScalingForWidth(100),true);
            popUp.showAtLocation(popUpView.findViewById(R.id.share_successfully_ctr),Gravity.CENTER,0, 0); 

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    popUp.dismiss();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r, 3000);           

        } else {
            showToast(result);
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a ImageViews(Gallery Images) inside of FrameLayOut. i compressed FrameLayout as JPEG. Now I want to share this Image on Twitter.Look at My Question.